# How to increase the number of tweets read using python for sentiment analyser

Tags: python, twitter

For the purpose of making a sentiment summariser i require to read large number of tweets.I use the following code to fetch tweets from twitter.The number of tweets returned are just 10 to 20.What changes can be made in this code to increase the number of tweets to 100 or more

```
t.statuses.home_timeline()

raw_input(query)

data = t.search.tweets(q=query)

for i in range (len(data['statuses'])):

     test = data['statuses'][i]['text'] 

     print test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it returns only 20 tweets. Use `Count` Parameter in your query. Here's [statuses/home_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline)  doc page.

[image]

So, below is the code to get 100 tweets. Also, it must be less than or equal to 200.

```
t.statuses.home_timeline(count=100)
```

**Updated at 4.48 after getting output**

I tried and got huge tweets in 50 & 100. Here's the code:

Save the below code as `test.py`. Create a new directory - Paste `test.py` & this latest [Twitter 1.14.1 library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter) in it - Click `Terminal` & go the path where you created your new directoy using `cd path` command - now run `python test.py`.

```
from twitter import *
t = Twitter(
            auth=OAuth('OAUTH_TOKEN','OAUTH_SECRET',
                       'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET')
           )
query = int(raw_input("Type how many tweets do you need:\n"))
x = t.statuses.home_timeline(count=query)
for i in range(query):

  print x[i]['text']
```

Comment: i gave the parameter as you specified. But the number of tweets returned is still the same.

Comment: Have a look at this [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter). This is what they had mentioned. Btw, can i know what exactly are you trying?

Comment: I wish to make a sentiment summariser and i require large number of tweets for the purpose of analysis.I require tweets in thousands to produce efficient output. If i can get atleast 200 in one tey i can iterate it. But i'm not getting 200 tweets when i give the parameter count=200.

Comment: What's library are you using?

Comment: i only use twitter library to execute these functions.

Comment: Yea..but there are some Twitter Library for Python Language like tweepy, python-twitter and some. You can see the entire list [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries). If i get to know what library you are using, i can try it to help you.

Comment: I used python-twitter initially and faced a few problems. After that i downloaded twitter-1.10.0 package and simply installed it.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It's working. Follow the code!

Comment: thanks for the help . but i also require to filter these tweets based on a keyword. I need a way to get the large number of filtered tweets.

Comment: Then you `Search API` instead of `Home Timeline`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the number of tweets an application can fetch in a single request. You need to iterate through the results to get more than what you are returned in a single request. Take a look at this [article](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines) on the twitter developer site that explains how to work with iterating through the results.

Note that the number of results also depends on the query you are searching for.